# Can somebody check if my workout is good for strength training & hypertrophy? Maybe give tips / adjustments if neccesary

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines, strength-training, hypertrophy

Hello this is my first post here, here is my workout program at the moment:

***Day 1***
*Back Squat* 5/3/1
*Good Morning* 3× 8-10
*Leg Extension* 3 sets x 8-10
*Front Foot Elevated Smith Machine Split Squat* 4× 8-10 & *Around the world kettlebell* 3 sets x 8-10

***Day 2***
*Bench Press* 5/3/1
*Incline Bench Press* 4× 8-10
*Strict Press* 3× 8-10
*Underhand Grip Pulldown* 3 sets x 8-10 reps
*Weighted Dips* 4 sets x 6-8 reps & *Dumbbell Rotational Swing* 4 sets x 8-10 reps

***Day 3***
*Deadlift* 5/3/1
*Hip Thrust* 3× 8-10
*Prone Leg Curl* 3× 8-10
*Pull Ups* 4 sets x amrap & *Toes to bar* 3 sets x amrap

***Day 4***
*Strict Press* 5/3/1
*Seated Incline Shoulder Press* 4 sets x 8-10 reps & *1Db Core Knee Raises* 4 sets x 8-10 reps (per side)
*Close-Grip Bench* 4x 8-10 (85%)
*Upright Row* 3× 8-10
*Reverse Delt Fly* 3× 8-10

***Day 5***
*Dumbbell Bicep Curl* 3 sets x 6-12 reps & *Chin Ups* 3 sets x amrap
*Hammer Curl* 3 sets x 6-12 reps & Tempo Chin Ups 3 sets x amrap
*Barbell Row* 3 sets x 10-12 reps
*Dumbbell Tricep Extension* 3 sets x 10-12 reps

My main goal is strength training with some hypertrophy.
Can you please let me know if it's a good program or if it needs any adjustments?